# How to grep from tee?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, tee

I want to check wether the output of my command contains "rerun" (and then rerun) but I also want to display the whole output. I know that I could use one of these:

```
command | tee >(grep rerun)
command | grep rerun
```

The first one prints the whole output as expected, but I can't use it as a condition because it always returns 0. The second one only prints the lines that contain rerun, but it returns 1 if there's no match.

My usage example:

```
while pdflatex paper.tex | grep -E "rerun LaTeX|run Biber"; do
    biber paper
done
```

[The answers provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/981601/3729508) also don't help because there grep always returns 0.

Comment: I also tried `command | tee >(echo) | grep rerun` but that doesn't give any output as well.

Comment: So you want the whole output, the matching lines or something else? I can't get the reason for such manipulations.

Comment: Yes I want the whole output, as stated in the question. There is also a reason given, by giving an exact usecase.

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
command | tee outfile | grep rerun
```

or

```
while pdflatex paper.tex | tee outfile | grep -E "rerun LaTeX|run Biber"; do
```

You can check the status of the grep command, and you can later look at the file "output".

Answer (score 1):

you could tee to a file and perform the grep on the file. Then you can use the grep exit code (0 when there's a match):

```
RERUN=1
while [[ $RERUN == 1 ]] ; do
  biber paper
  ! pdflatex paper.tex | tee output.txt && grep -E -q "rerun LaTeX|run Biber" output.txt
  RERUN=$?
done
```

The `!` on the 4th line inverses the exit code of the grep process because grep returns 0 when it finds a match and 1 when no match, see the [grep man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

> EXIT STATUS
>
> ```
>    Normally the exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were
>    selected, and 2 if an error occurred.  However, if the -q or --quiet or
>    --silent is used and a line is selected, the exit status is 0  even  if
>    an error occurred.
> ```

5th line puts the last exit code (`$?`) in the RERUN var which is used in the loop condition.

I also added the `-q` option to grep to not write to stdout

Comment: What does the `!` at the beginning of the fourth line do? Does it negate the output of `grep`?

Comment: @MaxMatti sorry for the late response, i was on vacation. yes, indeed, I updated the answer to answer your comment. Does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

If we stick with displaying `stdout` right away then the `grep` output in Process Substitution should be redirected to a file lest you get duplicated lines in the output, so you have to do for example this: `command | tee >(grep rerun >/tmp/my.log)`.

Once you have a file produced, all you have to do is to use `[[ -s /tmp/my.log ]]` as your rerun condition.